# How to assign aura:attribute for objects with default value null?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, aura-attribute, null

This must be a a very simple question, but may be I'm doing it wrong.

I wanted to set default aura:attribute value to null on lightning component as below.

e.g.

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedObj" type="Object" default="null"/>
```

but this gives me selectedValue as a String, and not comparing with `null` in lightning javascript controller/helper code.

let selectedObj = component.get('v.selectedObj');

```
console.log('selectedObj: '+(selectedObj===null) +' string comparison: '+(selectedObj==='null'));
component.set('v.selectedObj', null);
console.log('selectedObj: '+(component.get('v.selectedObj')==null)+' string comparison: '+(component.get('v.selectedObj')=='null'));
```

Result:

```
selectedObj: false string comparison: true 
selectedObj: true string comparison: false
```

Therefore I had to set null value explicitly in javascript controller at the initialization.
e.g.

```
component.set('v.selectedObj', null);
```

Is this the correct approach to set null in javascript? are there any better alternatives to set default null value for aura:attribute?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't define a default attribute. This causes the attribute to default to null.

Eg

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedObj" type="Object" />
```

Comment: too easy, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if it was bad to have such a short answer... But I couldn't think of anything else useful to add!